# Is it possible to include package structure to a flutter project documentation?

Tags: flutter, dart, dartdoc

I use [dartdoc](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc) to generate documentation of a Flutter project. The documentation is generated, but there is no structure to it.

For example if I have file structure like this

- DirA

  - Dir1

    - Widget1
    - Widget2
  - Widget3
- Widget4

The documentation stucture looks like this

- Widget1
- Widget2
- Widget3
- Widget4

How can I introduce structure to the documentation? Is it even possible? I did not find any solution. I tried to add <package_name>.dart file to every directory with exports only, but that did not help.